# set variable as first option in array php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have a select box being filled in with a mysql query, it functions fine and is selectable. Data changes and works fine.

It currently sorts based on the branch_id column and what I want is the session variable of $branch_id to be the first option of the select box. This is based on the branch selected from a previous page.

This is where I am stuck.

Here is some sample code of the branch dropdown.

This selection then changes a list of users that appears in an options box below this code. It all functions fine, I just need to refine it so the currently selected branch(from a prev page) is the first in the branch dropdown.

If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it.

```
//get list of allowed Branchs
$AllowBranch = "SELECT branch_id FROM access WHERE userid IN (SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = '{$_SESSION['user']}') ORDER BY branch_id ASC";
$getAllowBranch = mysql_query($AllowBranch);
while($getAllowBranchRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($getAllowBranch))
{
    $NameSQL = "SELECT name FROM branchlist WHERE id = '{$getAllowBranchRow['branch_id']}'";
    $Nameresult = mysql_query($NameSQL); 
    $Namerow = mysql_fetch_assoc($Nameresult);

    echo "<OPTION VALUE = '{$getAllowBranchRow['branch_id']}' "; if($NeedBranch == $getAllowBranchRow['branch_id']) { echo "selected"; } echo "> ".ucwords(strtolower($Namerow['name']));
}
echo "</SELECT>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code to see if the selected attribute is put in the right option tag. Also, you forgot to close every `<option>` tag with a `</option>`, not sure, but this could also be the problem.

Comment: thanks for the tip on the option closing. changed.
not sure what you mean by "see if the selected attribute is put in the right option tag"

Comment: Well, you call `if($NeedBranch == $getAllowBranchRow['branch_id']) {` and if that succeeds you add the `selected` attribute to your `<option>` tag, check if it actually does that. I'm basically saying, go to the site, and right-click the page and click view source code, head over to the `<select>` tag and check if one of the `<option>` tags has the selected attribute.

Comment: ok, gotcha. yes it does that. and if i select a new one and view the code the new branch has the selected tag.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have missing tag `<select name="<your field name>">` before `while` loop.

Then you have missing closing tag `</option>` too. You cannot solve your problem, if you have HTML broken.

So,  it should looks like this:

```
echo '<select name="<your field name>">';
while($getAllowBranchRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($getAllowBranch))
{
    $NameSQL = "SELECT name FROM branchlist WHERE id = '{$getAllowBranchRow['branch_id']}'";
    $Nameresult = mysql_query($NameSQL); 
    $Namerow = mysql_fetch_assoc($Nameresult);

    echo "<option value='" . $getAllowBranchRow['branch_id'] . "'" . $NeedBranch == $getAllowBranchRow['branch_id'] ? " selected" : "" . ">" . ucwords(strtolower($Namerow['name'])) . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

#### What I have done?

Firstly, I fixed your missing HTML tags. Then I just simply used [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to check if `branch_id` equals to `$NeedBrach` and if yes, add following string `selected` and if not, add nothing.

Don't forget to replace `<your field name>` with your expect `select` name.

#### Important final thoughts!

I have to remind using `mysql_*` is deprecated, you should use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead with [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2811746).

Comment: thanks for the replies guys. i couldn't get this to go no matter which way i tried so 'executive decision' it stays the way it is.
thanks for the support though and the help in trying to get it to work for me, much appreciated! :)